# Shapeless HList Containing a Sequence

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a String representation as below that I would like to represent as a HList. Here is it:

```
123456,/02/2017,0,0,0,0,0,0,170.153
```

So the type that I'm interested in is:

```
Int :: DateTime :: Seq[Double]
```

I was able to manage one-to-one mapping done, but how could I convert my representation above to the Shapeless type that I would want to? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where's your trouble. Why can't you just do something like:

```
def hlistFromString(s: String): Int :: Date :: Seq[Double] :: HNil = {
  val ss = s.split(',')
  ss(0).toInt :: new Date(ss(1)) :: ss.toSeq.drop(2).map(_.toDouble) :: HNil
}

val s = "123456,01/02/2017,0,0,0,0,0,0,170.153"
println(hlistFromString(s))
```

Output is

> 123456 :: Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 2017 :: ArrayBuffer(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 170.153) :: HNil

The only guess I have is that you missed that any `HList` type should end with `HNil`

Comment: Yes, I was indeed not paying attention to the HNil!